# C# 'SerialPort' does not contain a constructor that takes 6 arguments

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm working on a C# Windows application. I'm using Serial USB port to listening for data from the selected COM port

```
SerialPort sp;
string t;
void Serial(string port_name)
{
    sp = new SerialPort(port_name, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One,Handshake.None);

    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    sp.Open();
}

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string list = sp.ReadLine();
    listBox1.Items.Add(list);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t = "COM5";
    Serial(t);
}
```

But I get an error

> 'SerialPort' does not contain a constructor that takes 6 arguments

On here [image]

What is the problem here? If anyone knows please help me.

Comment: that is correct, it has up to 5 parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Handshake in Constructor, you must do it like this :

```
sp = new SerialPort(port_name, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well there are only [those](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) constructors

```
SerialPort()    
SerialPort(IContainer)  
SerialPort(String)  
SerialPort(String, Int32)   
SerialPort(String, Int32, Parity)   
SerialPort(String, Int32, Parity, Int32)    
SerialPort(String, Int32, Parity, Int32, StopBits)
```

So you probably want to change your initialization statement from

```
sp = new SerialPort(port_name, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One,Handshake.None);
```

to

```
sp = new SerialPort(port_name, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) SerialPort class haven't construcotr with 6 params.

`SerialPort(String, Int32, Parity, Int32, StopBits)` - Initializes a new instance of the SerialPort class using the specified port name, baud rate, parity bit, data bits, and stop bit.

Handshake - you cannot set it in constructor. 
You can set it in this way:

```
sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
```

Answer (score 0):

Handshake is not one of the parameter is SerialPort constructor.
There is a property "Handshake" in SerialPort class which can be set.
Default value is none.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.handshake(v=vs.110).aspx